# Проверка на наличие записи в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Пишу свой трехколесный CRUD. В связи с этим возникли следующие вопросы: хочу, чтобы операции INSERT и UPDATE были реализованы в одной функции обертке setEntry() (понимаю, что логика операций разделена для безопасности, но попытаюсь ненакосячить) вопрос- насколько уместна данная реализация?

И второй вопрос: часть данных при вставке новой записи(setEntry()) надо определить имеется ли данная запись вообще, но это получается уже два запроса - целесообразно так нагружать mysql?

И сообственно как вообще лучше сделать этот setEntry, чтобы в зависимости от существования записи он генерировал либо INSERT либо UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться расширенным синтаксисом оператора INSERT INTO

```
INSERT INTO tablename
SET
    key_field = 1,
    data_field1 = 2,
    data_field2 = 3
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    data_field1 = 2,
    data_field2 = 3;
```

В этом случае запись с ключем `key_field = 1` добавится если ее раньше не существовало, а  если она уже есть, то - обновится.

Comment: Спасибо похоже, то что надо!

Comment: А без указания полей таблицы никак не обойтись( мне для этого надо расширять и усложнять логику, причем придется вызывать show columns)?

Comment: В самом `INSERT` можно. `INSERT INTO tablename VALUE(...)`. А то что идет после `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` должно быть с обязательным указанием полей.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Для таких сложных запросов, где нужно что-то проверять на БД. Можно использовать хранимые процедуры. Так MySQL Будет нагружен меньше чем несколько запросов с PHP.

Comment: Понял о чем вы штука классная, но я боюсь потерять гибкость используя ее, так как в будущем хочу использовать еще и mongoDB(больше для опыта построения crud) так, что хочу реализовать все на примитивном уровне.